Does a positive proof for the Spin-Statistics theorem exist?
Most proofs I have found for the spin-statistics theorem have been "negative" proofs. That is, they proceed as follows

First, they show that half-integer spin states cannot be bosons, and integer spin states cannot be fermions.
Then, they state that as states can either be bosonic or fermionic, bosons must have integer spin, and fermions must have half-integer spin.

Such a proof is unsatisfying to me, as it

Is not a direct proof.
Forces us to somehow justify that states following parastatistics cannot exist.

So, is there a "positive" proof for the spin-statistics theorem, which directly proves that bosons must have integer spin, and fermions must have half-integer spin?

IIRC, as a matter of fact parastatistics can't exist above 2+1 dimensions.  And of course spin statistics theorem famously fails in low dimensions.

Anyons can't exist above 2+1 dimensions. Parastatistics can, from what I know. Also, I think one can extend the spin-statistics theorem to get an analogous result for 2+1 dimensions, but I'm not sure.
